# Ошибка при обращении к дочерним элементам

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Проблема заключается в обращении к дочернему элементу в функции each (jquery).
Вот код:

```
$.each($('body .post-img'),function(i, val){
    var pos = $(val).offset();
    //alert(pos.top + " " + i + " " + st);
   if (pos.top - 100 >= st) {
        alert(val.firstChild);
        val.firstChild.css({
            "transform" : "translate(0%, " + st / 20 + "%"
        });
   }
})
```

В строке 6: я пытаюсь обратится к первому элементу **val**, но это вызывает ошибку (val.firstChild.css is not a function). Внутри находится картинка (). Что делать?

Comment: какую ошибку это вызывает? Стоит проверить разметку, скорее всего у элемента с классом `post-img` нет дочерних элементов

Answer (score 0):

`val` как и `val.firstChild` - это нативные элементы, а не объекты jQuery.

У нативного элемента **отсутствует** метод `css`.

Метод `css` есть у объектов jQuery, следовательно перед вызовом этого метода, надо создать этот объект, обернув элемент в вызов `$(...)`

```
$(val.firstChild).css({...})
```